# What is the purpose of the first session ticket issued by an OpenSSL TLSv1.3 server?

Tags: openssl, tls1.3

With TLSv1.3, by default, an OpenSSL server creates 2 tickets, as described [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_new_session_ticket.html). This happens within the server's `SSL_do_handshake` call, after the actual TLSv1.3 handshake has finished internally.

Regarding session resumption, I have only ever seen clients use the second ticket that was issued, never the first.

I found no reason or recommendation in [rfc8446](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#page-73)'s various session ticket related chapters. Multiple tickets make it more difficult to track tickets for the purposes of associating server-side state (not least because of a few undocumented and exciting API "features"), or implementing single-use tickets as a potential security measure as described in [rfc8446 here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-8.1), because the semantics are not clear.

Why would the server create multiple tickets immediately after the handshake instead of just 1, and what is the purpose of the first ticket if clients only seem to care about the last one?